# Abstract methods with default parameters in Mono (Unity3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, polymorphism, abstract-class, abstract

I’m working on Unity3D game in C# ([Unity3D is based on Mono](http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html)).

I wrote an abstract class *CompositeConnector* declaring abstract methods. One of them, *DrawContent* has a default string parameter.

```
public abstract class CompositeConnector : ScriptableObject
{
// ... 
    public abstract void DrawContent(GUISkin skin, float zoom_factor, string control_name = "");
// ...
}
```

Other classes inheriting from CompositeConnector also declare a default parameter.

```
public class InputTextConnector : CompositeConnector
{
// ...
    public override void DrawContent(GUISkin skin, float zoom_factor, string control_name = "")
    {
    // ...
    }
// ...
}
```

My problem comes when I call this method without the latest parameter.

```
// Produces the error.
_input_connector.DrawContent(_skin, _zoom_factor);
// No error.
_input_connector.DrawContent(_skin, _zoom_factor, "");
```

I get an error such as (not at runtime):

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Key duplication when
>   adding: Void DrawContent(UnityEngine.GUISkin, Single, System.String)

As you can see if I set the parameter and don't rely with the default value I don't get the error. I tried a lot of various combination but the only solution I found was to not use default parameters.

Is this a known issue? Am I trying to do something wrong here?

Comment: Is this in a Unity script?  It's perfectly valid to do this in C#.  The error looks like it might come from the script processing code in Unity rather than from the C# compiler.

Comment: @corey thanks for your comment. So you confirm that it's valid in C#? It might comes from Unity then. :/ Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, I tested it to make sure.  However I also found some references to bugs in Mono that relate to this one.  It looks like it could be a problem with the handling of abstract base classes.  You could try defining an interface instead... might help, might not.

Comment: Can you point these references  to bugs you were talking about please? Thanks again!

Comment: This for instance: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/internal-compiler-error-when-importing-dll-into-project.178651/
Googling the error message with 'unity' as an additional keyword turns up a few results that may relate.

Comment: You can do an overload the method too.